# Notepad++ method autocompletion

Tags: regex, methods, autocomplete, notepad++

I'd like to create a auto-completion definition file to my domain specific language so that the I get parameter hints for predefined class methods.

In the [doc](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Auto_Completion#Path_completion) I have the following example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Windows-1252" ?>
   <NotepadPlus>
   <AutoComplete language="C++">
   <Environment ignoreCase="no" startFunc="(" stopFunc=")" paramSeparator="," terminal=";" additionalWordChar = "."/>
   <KeyWord name="abs" func="yes">
       <Overload retVal="int" descr="Returns absolute value of given integer">
           <Param name="int number" />
       </Overload>
   </KeyWord>
```

That works like a charm for function calls such as:

```
abs(-12)
```

That is, I hit "a" and Notepad++ suggests the function *abs* and hints to its parameters.

However what if *abs* is a method of a class? For instance:

```
MyObject.abs(-12)
```

I would expect that once I hit the key "." and "a" Notepad++ would propose me the *abs* method and all the parameter hints.  However, with the xml definition listed above it does not work.

Does anybody know how to deal with this issue? Is there a regular expression mode that we can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out solution. Posting here to leave a trace and help others out.
If I remove `additionalWordChar = "."` it wokrs!

Comment: Perhaps with `additionalWordChar = "."` present the word being matched against the `KeyWord name="..."` field is `MyObject.a` or `MyObject.abs`. It may be worth experimenting with a new section starting `<KeyWord name="MyObject.abs"`. (Alter the description so you can see which entry matches when both are present.)